# Get Data from Dynamically Created textboxes in Angular using ng-for

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've created a set of dynamically created textboxes like so

```
  <input id="Pun{{item}}" type="text" 
    class="form-control textbox" placeholder=Punishment >

</div>
```

Where punishmentnum is an array of numbers. I want to know how to get data from each of the created textboxes, any help is appreciated.

Comment: us an `[(ngModel)] to bind to each input

Comment: I tried to do that, but it made all of the text duplicate in the other text boxes.

Comment: try using ngfor with a `trackby` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a solution on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tebwgc?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Update the for each input with value iterated by `*ngFor` value as below.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <input id="Pun{{item}}" type="text" [(ngModel)]="pun[item]" 
    name="pun[item]" class="form-control textbox" placeholder="punishment 
  {{item}}" > {{pun}}
</div>
```

where

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
pun = [];
```

Comment: I have improved your answer, but please take some time to read [answer]

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.getElementById().

Your HTML file:

```
  <input id="Pun{{item}}" type="text" class="form-control textbox" placeholder=Punishment>
```

Your ts file:

```
 var item="YOUR_ITEM_HERE";
 var textValue = (document.getElementById("Pun"+item) as any).value;
```